# error when running react native application for the first time

Tags: android, react-native

After creating the project using the command "`react-native init test`". I just run "`react-native run-android`".

it gives me the following error in node command prompt:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
>
> at parse (native)
>
> at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)
>
> { [Error: write EPIPE] code: 'EPIPE', errno: 'EPIPE', syscall: 'write' }

and my app shows like:

[image]

whats wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. 
Switching to `react-native@0.42.0` and `react@15.4.1` works for me.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12885